How to concat video using ffmpeg in server linux in ASP.NET Core MVC
My .NET Core project uses ffmpeg to join videos, I used it on my local machine and it worked fine and pushed it to git, then merged and ran the pipeline to build it to the linux server via docker, however after running the pipeline, I couldn't use ffmpeg, I tried ways like adding PATH to the server but it didn't work, I installed ffmpeg on the server and ran it successfully using the terminal.
Please show me how to make ffmpeg run when my code is on the server.
_logger.LogInformation($"PATH: {Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH")}"); // /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin (not have PATH of ffmpegg although I place it on server)
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = $@"ffmpeg",
                    Arguments = $@"-version",
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                };

using var process = Process.Start(processInfo);

var outputTask = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
var errorTask = process.StandardError.ReadToEndAsync();

_logger.LogInformation($"outputTask: {await outputTask}");
_logger.LogInformation($"errorTask: {await errorTask}");


Exception: No such file or directory


My guess is ffmpeg just isn't available in the Docker container. Installing it directly on the server won't make it accessible inside the container. Have you added the installation in your Dockerfile?

I don't know how to install it properly

You said "i tried this way on dockerFile but it's not work". What do you mean it doesn't work? Have you tried using exec to check if you're able to call the binary?

Because I code and push to gitlab, then merge and run CI/CD, in my company's source code there is a DockerFile and I add the ffmpeg installation script to it, I don't know how to use exec to test when running with CI/CD

could you try this below code in your Dockerfile to output the ffmpeg version during the build process to see if the ffmpeg is correctly installed or not:
`# Base image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
Install ffmpeg
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ffmpeg
Verify ffmpeg installation
RUN ffmpeg -version
Continue with the rest of your Dockerfile
COPY . .
Build, publish, and run your application
(the rest of your Dockerfile)`
